# How to "link" two ranges together in swift

Tags: swift, range

I have a function that produces a random number output (see below). I'd like for it to choose that output from either 0-50 or 150-400, but not in between. I couldn't find much about it on my own... so if any of you could post either resources or an answer that would be awesome! Thanks so much in advance!

The three question marks are where I assume some operator would go.

```
func random() -> UInt32 {
        var range = UInt32(0)...UInt32(50) ??? UInt32(150)...UInt32(400)
        return range.startIndex + arc4random_uniform(range.endIndex - range.startIndex + 1)
}
```

I tried using the + operator and the | operator, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a union of ranges to `arc4random_uniform()`.

What you can do is to create a random number in a single interval and then "adjust" all numbers which are not in the first range to the second range:

```
func random() -> UInt32 {
    var x = arc4random_uniform(302) // 0 .. 301
    if (x > 50) {
        // map 51 .. 301 to 150 .. 400:
        x += 99
    }
    return x
}
```

This can be generalized to multiple ranges (now updated for Swift 3):

```
func randomNumber(fromRanges ranges: Range<UInt32>...) -> UInt32 {
    let totalLength = ranges.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.upperBound - $1.lowerBound)}
    var rnd = arc4random_uniform(totalLength)
    for range in ranges {
        if rnd < range.upperBound - range.lowerBound {
            return rnd + range.lowerBound
        }
        rnd -= range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
    }
    fatalError("this should never be reached")
}

let x = randomNumber(fromRanges: 0 ..< 51, 150 ..< 401)
```

Comment: This is of course not really new, but I haven't found a duplicate yet. I hope that at least the Swift implementation is new.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to ranges is to just use a while loop to make sure you get a value in the range you want.

```
func randomFunc() -> UInt32 {
    var rand: UInt32 = 401
    while rand < 0 || rand > 400 || (rand > 50 && rand < 150){
        rand = arc4random_uniform(400)
    }
    return rand;
}
```